# Populando um select com Angular2 e Firebase

Tags: angular, firebase

blz?
EStou iniciando em Angular2 e estou achando o Firebase um backend bem melhor que o Backand, pois em pouquíssimo tempo consegui conectar ao Firebase.
A questão agora é, estou tentando popular um select mas tá vindo sem os nomes. Vem quatro itens, mas vazios.
Vamos ao código HTML

```html
<label>Escolha a marca</label>
<select materialize="material_select" [materializeSelectOptions]="selectOptions" class="browser-default">
  <option  *ngFor="let marca of marcas | async">{{ nome }}</option>
</select>
```

E agora uma imagem do banco Firebase

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém que já manje disso pra me dar um help?
Valeu, abraços!

Comment: Você testou marca.nome ?

Comment: Não, boa ideia!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu tive esse mesmo problema, mas consegui solucionar. Espero poder ajudar você.

O componente precisa obrigatoriamente iterar com a lista definida em [materializeSelectOptions]="selectOptions". Então, no seu caso, basta usar
[materializeSelectOptions]="marcas" (que é o array assíncrono que será percorrido).

Já as options ficam:

{{ marca.nome }}

Comment: Algo realmente mudou, mas ainda não deu certo!
<select _ngcontent-rdx-4="" class="browser-default" materialize="material_select" ng-reflect-materialize="material_select" ng-reflect-materialize-select-options="[object Object]">
  <!--template bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object]"
}--><option _ngcontent-rdx-4=""></option><option _ngcontent-rdx-4=""></option><option _ngcontent-rdx-4=""></option><option _ngcontent-rdx-4=""></option>
</select>

Note os [object Object]

Answer (score 0):

Mas agora esta retornando o array devido. Só que dentro de cada marca, você possui um objeto {logotipo, nome}.

Você precisa acessar a string alvo ***marca.nome***:

```html
<option  *ngFor="let marca of marcas | async">{{ marca.nome }}</option>
```